# Where do I define Arbitrary instances?

Tags: haskell, dependencies, code-coverage, haskell-stack, quickcheck

I can't figure out where to define `Arbitrary` instances for my datatype. If I put it *in* the package, then the package unnecessarily has to have `QuickCheck` as a dependency. If I put it *in* the tests, then other packages can't make use of the instance. If I put it in a separate test-utils package then the tests *also* have to live in a separate package so it's an orphan instance and *also* `stack test --coverage` doesn't work.

What other options are there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd usually pick the separate package option — but then I don't use `stack test --coverage`. Thanks for introducing me to it!

(Edit: I'd probably do this, and then use the test flag option only for running `stack test --coverage --flag thepackage:arbitrary` so that nobody else has to deal with the flags.)

It may also be worth raising the `--coverage` issue on the `stack` issue tracker, as it would be good for the coverage check to work in this case.

You ask for other options — the best one is probably a test flag.

## A test flag

It is possible to define a flag in your cabal file (defaulting to false) which will only build the modules with your QuickCheck dependency if the flag is selected.

Place the required code in the directory `arbitrary` (for example). Then add the equivalent of the following to the relevant parts of your `package.yaml` (1st snippet) or `the-library.cabal` (2nd snippet) file:

```
flags:
  arbitrary:
    description: Compile with arbitrary instances
    default: false
    manual: true

library:
  ⁝
  when:
  - condition: flag(arbitrary)
    dependencies:
    - QuickCheck
    source-dirs:
    - arbitrary
```

```
flag arbitrary
  description: Compile with arbitrary instances
  manual: True
  default: False

library
  ⁝
  if flag(arbitrary)
    hs-source-dirs:
      arbitrary
    build-depends:
      QuickCheck
```

Then, packages which want to use the instances should add the following in their `stack.yaml` (1st) or `cabal.project` (2nd) files:

```
flag:
  the-library:
    arbitrary: true
```

```
constraints: the-library +arbitrary
```

But there's a slight problem… there is currently no way for that library to only depend on the `+arbitrary` version in only its test suite, unless it also defines such a flag. This may be a price worth paying.

Note: I haven't tested the downstream packaging, yet.

[Ivan Milenovic's blog](https://ivanmiljenovic.wordpress.com/2010/09/03/test-dependencies-in-cabal/) was useful as an initial resource.

## DerivingVia/Generic instances

There may be another possibility, now that GHC 8.6 has been released, with `DerivingVia`. There's a case study in [Blöndal, Löh & Scott (2018)](https://www.kosmikus.org/DerivingVia/deriving-via-paper.pdf) for `Arbitrary` instances.

You would create newtype wrappers, and implement `Arbitrary` for those newtypes.

It doesn't quite avoid the problem, as is. But you may be able to implement `Generic` for those newtypes in such a way that the instances derivable using `generic-arbitrary` match what you'd want.

---

There may be some other options. In particular, `QuickCheck`'s dependencies aren't actually that heavy. And there are other testing libraries, too. Plus, note that there has been some discussion of separating an `Arbitrary`-like typeclass into a standalone library.

I would also have suggested internal libraries, but that doesn't allow other packages to use your instances.